# Could not get data from serialized array using unserialize function

Tags: php, serialization

I have serialized data and I am using PHP unserialize function which is not working for me. I do not know what is wrong with this string. This is how my serialized data look like. My PHP knowledge is limited so I could not figure out the issue in this data. Can any one help me with this.

```
s:73:"a:5:{i:0;s:4:"8941";i:1;s:4:"8939";i:2;s:4:"8942";i:3;s:4:"8946";i:4;s:4:"8950";}";
```

Comment: @Remy I replaced 2 with 4. Can you tell me what else is wrong in this  string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a serialized *string* that contains a serialized *array*.  The *string* length is `81` not `73`.

`s:81:"`*characters in between the first and last quotes and in the example there are 81*`"`

```
$string = 's:81:"a:5:{i:0;s:4:"8941";i:1;s:4:"8939";i:2;s:4:"8942";i:3;s:4:"8946";i:4;s:4:"8950";}";';
$result = unserialize($string);
```

Yields the serialized *array*:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:4:"8941";i:1;s:4:"8939";i:2;s:4:"8942";i:3;s:4:"8946";i:4;s:4:"8950";}
```

Unserialize that:

```
$array = unserialize($result);
```

Yields the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8941
    [1] => 8939
    [2] => 8942
    [3] => 8946
    [4] => 8950
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. What are the meaning of s here. How you calculated its value which is 81